# Как добавить свои поля в woocommerce checkout, если в корзине виртуальный товар?

Tags: woocommerce

Всем привет, есть трудность с добавление своих полей в woocommerce checkout при условии, что в корзине виртуальный товар. 
написал вот такой код https://gist.github.com/pavelbonddesign/91da027d6d501e867d7050afe30a734c
но он работает только если в корзине только виртуальный товар, но не срабатывает, когда в корзине кроме виртуального товара есть и другие товары.